# TCL for DC: regexp matching of non-standard hierarchical names

Tags: regex, tcl

I'm trying to write some automation scripts for Synopsys Design Compiler, but I have troubles with the following case:

I see that there are logic tie-off nets which have the following name:

```
dc_shell> all_connected foo_top/foo/foo_pin
{foo_top/*Logic0*}
```

In my script I want to detect which pins are connected to logic tie-offs:

```
set connected_nets [find net [all_connected $pin]]
foreach_in_collection net $connected_nets {
     if {[regexp {.*Logic0.*} [get_object_name $net]] } {
          # skip this pin because it is tied to logic 0
          continue
     }
}
```

This matching never succeeds. It works for all other pins and nets, but fails on tie-offs.

I get a feeling that it has something to do with the fact that tie-off net is specified with * in the name, but I'm not sure how to handle it.

What can I do to overcome this and be able to detect these tie-off nets?

Thanks

Comment: If you try the invocation `regexp {.*Logic0.*} {foo_top/*Logic0*}` you will get 1, so it's not the matching that fails. It would seem that the command `get_object_name` doesn't return what you expect it to. Note also that the regular expression `{.*Logic0.*}` is equivalent to the regular expression `{Logic0}`.

Comment: @Hoodiecrow, thanks for your comment. It helped me to understand that the issue is not related to regexp and I found it. Can you please add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try the invocation `regexp {.*Logic0.*} {foo_top/*Logic0*}` you will get 1, so it's not the matching that fails. It would seem that the command `get_object_name` doesn't return what you expect it to.

---

As a side note, the regular expression `{.*Logic0.*}` is equivalent to the regular expression `{Logic0}` for the purpose of determining presence of a pattern. Unless you add some kind of anchor, like `^` or `$`, regular expression matching adds an implied `.*` to either end of the expression you provide.

On the other hand, the variants are *not* equivalent when capturing the match:

```
set fbb foobarbaz
set pat1 bar
set pat2 {.*bar.*}

if {[regexp -- $pat1 $fbb] == [regexp -- $pat2 $fbb]} {puts "the same"}
# => the same

set cap1 [regexp -inline -- $pat1 $fbb]
set cap2 [regexp -inline -- $pat2 $fbb]
if {$cap1 ne $cap2} {puts "not the same: $cap1 vs $cap2"}
# => not the same: bar vs foobarbaz
```

Answer (score 1):

To match the string `*Logic0*` using a regular expression isn't *too* hard. It does require a little care though, since `*` is a regular expression metacharacter and the RE quote character is `\` which is also a Tcl metacharacter. We're talking one of these

```
regexp "\\*Logic0\\*" [get_object_name $net]
```

```
regexp {\*Logic0\*} [get_object_name $net]
```

```
# Magic prefix. ONLY for matching where the rest is literal!
regexp "***=*Logic0*" [get_object_name $net]
```

In general, I'd go with this:

```
regexp {\*Logic0\*} [get_object_name $net]
```

since that's easier when adapting to handle more different names (maybe with `{\*Logic\d+\*}` so `*Logic1*` and `*Logic42*` also match?)